# Regular Expression - Ensuring Token Order

Tags: regex, delphi

I have a regular expression I am using.

```
^(?=.*?\bone)(?=.*?\btwo)(?=.*?\bthree).*$
```

This says.. Match "one" as a Starting word, "two" as a starting word and "three" as a starting word.  Unfortunately, it does NOT ensure order.

For example, the expression above will match "abc ones two fours threes fives", in effect ensuring that "one" "two" and "three" is in my text.  How do ensure ORDER.  Specifically, that "one" comes before "two" which comes before "three"?

So.. "ones twos fours threes" should match, but "fours twos ones threes" should NOT match...

I am using Delphi XE6 if that makes any difference (which I don't expect does...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the three positive lookaheads into one positive lookahead, ensuring the order of which String must come first

```
^(?=.*?\bone.*?\btwo.*?\bthree).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the order then remove the lookarounds.

```
^.*?\bone\b.*?\btwo\b.*?\bthree\b
```

or

```
^(?:(?!\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b).)*?\bone\b(?:(?!\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b).)*?\btwo\b(?:(?!\bone\b|\btwo\b|\bthree\b).)*?\bthree\b
```